# Bitcoin successfully deducted on sender wallet but did not reach receiver wallet

Tags: confirmations, fraud

[image]

Here is the wallet address for receiver: `1Gouzjo9Jav1k4AmRoUJJMzidVfnMoSieS`.
I had used the Blockchair site to see and track status. Based on the details, account had seen receiving last 21 hours. Also on the picture, there is no check icon on this transaction. I'm referring to 0.026 BTC. Thanks for those who will answer and help track this transaction.[image]