# I sent Bitcoin to an address but the recipient hasn't yet received it

Tags: transactions, fraud, lost-transactions

This is the transaction ID:
81f0babd0a3c6d9be17db45a62932679b05bac6a30df1abfb47c2eee83d9f0ff. The address is not wrong but the receiver couldn't get the payment. It has been 2 days.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/89673/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/92058/5406