# missing transaction not received

Tags: blockchain

I transfered 0.013 mBTC into Bitoincore.org wallet.on the 07/07/2020. As yet I have not received
Hash:-

13290114c5e1fe381c707e5f67b246cd0260f5bd24c9a1fc1aed0eab08dd2521

Address:-

1AKWvdsoAQC43sBANr9pCnk74nHCdrAvB6

0.0126 after fee, not recieved, can someone help me please

Comment: Why do you say "not received" exactly? What is telling you that the transaction is missing or hasn't been received? The transaction [executed successfully](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/13290114c5e1fe381c707e5f67b246cd0260f5bd24c9a1fc1aed0eab08dd2521).

Comment: Is your Bitcoin Core synced with the network?

Comment: Ok it is on the blockchain, but it is not showing in my wallet, the balance has not gone up by 0.0126mBTC.

Comment: I synced twice since 07/07/2020

Comment: The Address was generated by the Bitcoin core wallet. It is the same address as the last transaction that went into the account, but that one worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Synchronisation

If the bottom of the main window of your Bictoincore.org wallet looks like this, you need to wait for it to catch up (it is still busy downloading details of recent transactions)

[image: bitcoin-core's status-bar]

The icon at bottom right (two arrows moving in a circle) indicates the wallet is busy "catching up".

### What wallets really contain

Remember that wallets don't actually contain money and don't really receive money. They provide a view of the public blockchain - a list of completed transactions that every wallet either creates its own copy of, or in the case of other types of wallet (SPV etc) has access to some other way. If the blockchain data says you have received the money, you have received it. Regardless of what your wallet says.

The only important data in any wallet is a secret number called a "private key".

### The public blockchain is the only truth

As you know, when I write "blockchain", I mean the concept, not any of the many unrelated businesses who subsequently used that word opportunistically as their name or part of their name. I suspect their use of this name can confuse people.

There are many public [websites that offer a view of the blockchain](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explore). By checking a transaction-id or address in several of these you can find out whether you have received money - regardless of what your wallet says. You don't need a wallet to receive money in Bitcoin. You only really need a wallet when the time comes to spend money in Bitcoin. Including when you use it to purchase other currency.

---

### Checking whether a transaction is complete

A [randomly chosen blockchain explorer](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/13290114c5e1fe381c707e5f67b246cd0260f5bd24c9a1fc1aed0eab08dd2521) says

```
2020-07-07 19:45    Block 638188    1711 confirmations

Senders                          Recipients

10.73060786 BTC  bc1q7⋯zpemf     38Un8⋯7YWqm   0.00279737 BTC  
                                 13bVn⋯gxQig   0.01100000 BTC  Unspent
                                 1AKWv⋯rAvB6   0.01260000 BTC  Unspent
                                 1JAE7⋯W5sDP   0.03600000 BTC  
                                 3BMEX⋯f958k   0.23655533 BTC  
                                 bc1q7⋯zpemf  10.43155304 BTC
```

(I shortened the addresses to make the table fit here)

So 0.0126 BTC has definitely been received by the owner(s) of whatever wallet(s) contain the private-key from which was derived address 1AKWvdsoAQC43sBANr9pCnk74nHCdrAvB6

### Wallet problems

If your wallet doesn't show this, there can be several causes

- Your wallet is not fully synced as far as block 638188
- You don't in fact have the private-key from which that address was ultimately derived.
- Something else.

---

### Checking whether a Bitcoin Core wallet knows about a transaction

In Bitcoin core it is usually obvious if the wallet has not finished synchronisation. You will see a message like this:

[image: Synchronising Warning]

If not you can check from the "Debug Window" in the "Help" menu

[image: Menu]

Then you can click the "console" tab and then type command `getblockcount` at the bottom

[image: getBlockCount example command]

Here we see this wallet has only retrieved blocks as far as 554269

Therefore this wallet would not know about your transaction in block 638188.

---

### Related questions:

- [I sent Bitcoin to an address but the recipient hasn't yet received it. It has been 2 days](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/93145/13866)
- [Someone else created a wallet for me to use. Is this a scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/88910/13866)
- [What kinds of wallets are there?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866)
- [How do I import a private key into Bitcoin-Core?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5941/13866)

Comment: Yes I have synced twice since 07/07/2020

Comment: How do spend money off the blockchain when the wallet you are using has no funds to send???

Comment: After reading a bit more about bitcoin, I have used the same address twice, will this have anything to do with it not appearing in my wallet?

Comment: @NW: 1) Fully synced? 2) By using the wallet to construct and broadcast a draft transaction using the results of a mathematical calculation involving your private key from your wallet and the unspent transaction output data of prior transactions from the public blockchain. 3) No.

Comment: @NW: See updated answer

Comment: Hi Redgrittybrick, I have loaded the Bitcoin Core wallet on to my laptop, but there is no log-in. How does the wallet on my phone sync to the laptop wallet. The laptop wallet is busy syncing, but still has another 4 years to catch up. But I suspect this is a brand new wallet????

Comment: @NW: If two wallets each have the same secret number they will both show the same amount of money and both allow you to spend it. The synchronisation is the wallet downloading the list of all Bitcoin transactions ever made anywhere in the world to work out how much money you have.  If you have a login, you are probably using a custodial kind of wallet where some business is looking after your cash instead of you taking full control of your own cash yourself.  See [What kinds of wallet are there?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866).

Comment: At the end of the day is there any way that I can get my money back?

Comment: @NW: Back from where? Your 0.0126BTC hasn't gone anywhere, you still have it, no-one else has it. All you need to do is to set up a functioning wallet **that contains the relevant private-key**.

Comment: That address is the same address as the second transaction on the chain to the Bitcoin core wallet, it was generated from the same wallet??????????

Comment: How can I do a block count with the android app on my phone, although the app is synced, there is not as much functionality on the app??

Comment: @NW In your question you said *"I transfered 0.013 mBTC into Bitoincore.org wallet."* - but The Bitcoin core wallet isn't available on Android. Are you using the Schildbach wallet?

Comment: @NW: You may be better off asking your follow-up questions as actual questions [like this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/97213/13866)

Comment: The block is 641138

Comment: and that wallet is the one, this is so confusing, the address was produced by this wallet, it is the same as the last transaction I made that worked???????

Comment: Still no luck, still on the block unspent, I used same addrrss as the last transaction into and from same wallets, but the second transaction has not shown in the wallet. How do I bring the address into the wallet?

Comment: @NW that's not how things work. If your Schildback wallet on android generated the 1AKWv⋯rAvB6 receiving address, it already has that address (it should be listed in the address book). You can import addresses into a wallet but that is pointless as you then can only see but cannot *control or spend* any money sent that address.

Comment: So are you saying I have lost the money and what do you mean by Schilback wallet????

Comment: @NW, No. The Schildbach wallet is a wallet for Android phones created by Andreas Schildbach which is nowadays called "Bitcoin Wallet" by "Bitcoin Wallet Developers, the current version is "Wallet 8.05"" - you can see this by touching the three-dots menu at top-right and selecting "Settings" then "About". It's icon on android is an orange circle with a tilted Bitcoin currency symbol "B" in white.  --- Because "Bitcoin Wallet" is such a hopelessly general name, many people still call it the Schildbach wallet to distinguish this "Bitcoin Wallet" from all the hundreds of other Bitcoin wallet apps.

Comment: Sorry for being well stupid, but I want to do is get the money usable, will that be possible.

Comment: @NW. It should be possible but only if you can either get a clear understanding of how everything works or are able to explain what you did about ten times more clearly and carefully. I'm assuming something minor went wrong and that you are not the victim of a trickster who gave you false instructions to cheat you..

Comment: I sent a transaction from a crypto .com wallet which had the last transaction address stored on a white paper in the app. It was from a previous tr

Comment: That I did the same two wallets, sent it and it got to the blockchain but did appear in the Bitcoin wallet.If you look at the address on the blockchain click the hash you see all tr

Comment: The transactions that I have done and the 126 sats ar

Comment: I didn't write anything my only crime was use a recieving address twice, I now know that is not a done thing, can you help.  If you want money I can spare a little if I get it back

Comment: @NW I don't want any money. Please don't offer money to helpers. You'll just attract scammers who will trick you. Using an address twice isn't a problem - it just means your actions are not as private as they could be. That doesn't prevent money being transferred.

Comment: So is the app wallet thats at fault?

Comment: Hi pal, have you had any ideas on how I can retrieve my money?

Comment: How do I get to the debug menu on  app wallet??

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but how do you test a private key to generate a key for a transaction that has not fully completed?

Comment: Downloaded Electrum transfered seed hey presto funds back in my posession

Answer (score 1):

The hash mentioned is already confirmed on blockchain. It is already credited to receiver.  You can see it [here](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/13290114c5e1fe381c707e5f67b246cd0260f5bd24c9a1fc1aed0eab08dd2521)

So, it must be issue with your local node syncing.

Comment: Can you look in to this for me please?

Comment: Ok thanks, the wallet is on my phone, how do I transfer it to my laptop, for more functionality?

Comment: Are still there

Comment: How do I get to debug in the app?