# How to see highest available block number in "Bitcoin Wallet" app for Android (Schildbach wallet)?

Tags: block, bitcoin-wallet-app

If I have downloaded the "Bitcoin Wallet" by "Bitcoin Wallet Developers" (Schildbach wallet) onto an Android phone from the Google Play store, how can I see the latest block number that the wallet knows about?

Answer (score 2):

At the main screen tap the menu icon (three dots at top right) and choose "Network Monitor" from the available options.

[image: Menu]

Then swipe left to switch from the "Peers" tab to the "Blocks" tab.

[image: Blocks]

The top of this list shows the highest block number that the app knows about.