# Can I use the Bitcoin Core command line to confirm that the bitcoin I sent to an external address was confirmed and arrived? If so, how?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

I understand that one can use a node to ensure that transactions have been confirmed. If I sent bitcoin from my wallet to a friend living in another country, how can I use the command line on the Bitcore Core software to confirm that my transaction was confirmed by the bitcoin protocol and was received by my friend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`bitcoin-cli gettransaction {txid}`](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/gettransaction.html) will tell you the number of confirmations.

If the number of confirmations is greater than zero, the recipient has received the money. Even if their wallet is on a device that is turned off. Even if their wallet has been deleted. Recipients play no role in receiving money. *There is no time between confirmation and arrival of money*.

Sometimes recipients don't yet know they have received money because their wallets have not yet found out they have received money. Nevertheless, they have already received money. It is under their control and no-one else's.

See answer to

- [I sent Bitcoin to an address but the recipient hasn't yet received it](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/93145/13866)

Comment: Is the `gettransaction` method mentioned above conditional on me enabling the `txindex=1`? Otherwise, I think it only works as long as I used Bitcoin Core as my wallet, no?