# BTC payment sent and confirmed in blockchain but haven’t received in other wallet!

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Help!! It was confirmed about 34+ times but this is the first time this has ever happened to me! Usually it’s a piece of cake or at least it’ll show up in my account as “pending” but I don’t see it as a deposit to my wallet AT ALL and it’s been over 6 hours. Plz help.

Transaction ID: 7e444a3d0c6425b72bb200d54fe9b85564bdac616b36da3ef81481571947f09c

Thanks in advance!
Celeste [image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bitcoin successfully deducted on sender wallet but did not reach receiver wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/89673/bitcoin-successfully-deducted-on-sender-wallet-but-did-not-reach-receiver-wallet)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this transaction and there's nothing you can do to fix it. A common type of scam is to launch fraudulent exchange websites that don't even check if they received your payment. If you e-mail their support, then they might change your transaction to "processing" but then it'll be stuck at processing until they shut down the website.

Comment: Do I email the support where I sent the bitcoin TO? Or FROM?

Comment: You can e-mail them "This transaction [Transaction ID] pays [amount] to the address you gave me [recipient address]". (By the way, am I reading the question correctly: You've sent from your wallet to a company and not the opposite?)

Comment: I sent bitcoin from my CEX.IO wallet to my Cash App Bitcoin Wallet. Usually it posts within 5-10minutes. This time is hasn’t even showed up as received in my cash app.

Comment: Then you shouldn't write to CEX.IO support. Can you see the address Cash App generated in the the transaction, when you open it on a blockchain explorer?

Comment: Yes. I just checked it. This is what it says  I’ll add the photo to original question

Comment: Then you should contact the developers of Cash App Bitcoin wallet. It can be a bug.

Comment: I posted the photo. I’m not sure what it means though

Comment: Did you see the photo I posted ?

Comment: Yes, your coins should arrive if `19W2...` is your address. I'm not familiar with Cash App Bitcoin wallet so I can't help further than suggesting to relaunch the wallet.

Comment: Don't worry, I've found that you're not the only person experiencing that problem. At https://www.reddit.com/r/CashApp/comments/gsqd2l/cashapp_wont_update_my_balance/ or more specificly https://www.reddit.com/r/CashApp/comments/gsni2d/megathread_missing_bitcoin_deposits_after/ it seems there's a problem at their end. You should receive your coins after it undergoes maintenance. [Official announcement](https://www.reddit.com/r/CashApp/comments/gsni2d/megathread_missing_bitcoin_deposits_after/fs7olci/)